# R program dealing with missing values (Similar to apply function in Python)

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I am new to 'R' program and currently want to deal with the missing values.
Basically, I have a dataset with a few columns and there are missing values in the 'Purchase' column.

I want to impute the mean of Purchase values based on 'Master_Category' column for the missing values.

(Python code)

```
# generate missing Purchase values    
miss_Purch_rows = dataset['Purchase'].isnull()

# Check Purchase values from the grouping by the newly created Master_Product_Category column
categ_mean = dataset.groupby(['Master_Product_Category'])['Purchase'].mean()

# Impute mean Purchase value based on Master_Product_Category column
dataset.loc[miss_Purch_rows,'Purchase'] = dataset.loc[miss_Purch_rows,'Master_Product_Category'].apply(lambda x: categ_mean.loc[x])
```

I am looking for a similar code in 'R-program' to impute missing values by mean and relating to another column.

Sample data of the dataset is as follows;

```
   User_ID Product_ID    Gender Age  Occupation   Marital_Status Master_Category Purchase
1  1000001  P00000142      F 0-17         10              0             345    13650
2  1000001  P00004842      F 0-17         10              0            3412    13645
3  1000001  P00025442      F 0-17         10              0             129    15416
4  1000001  P00051442      F 0-17         10              0            8170     9938
5  1000001  P00051842      F 0-17         10              0             480     2849
6  1000001  P00057542      F 0-17         10              0             345       NA
7  1000001  P00058142      F 0-17         10              0            3412    11051
8  1000001  P00058242      F 0-17         10              0            3412       NA
9  1000001  P00059442      F 0-17         10              0            6816    16622
10 1000001  P00064042      F 0-17         10              0            3412     8190
```

I have tried ;

```
with(dataset, sapply(X = Purchase, INDEX = Master_Category, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please share the data using `dput` in R?

Comment: I have now added the data in the Question

Comment: You can use the `reticulate` package to use Python in R

Comment: Is there a function in R, to carry out imputing mean values?
I have tried ;
with(dataset, sapply(X = Purchase, INDEX = Master_Category, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of per-group operation is usually easy to do via the **tidyverse** set of packages:

First, we read in your example data:

```
txt <- 'User_ID Product_ID    Gender Age  Occupation   Marital_Status Master_Category Purchase
1000001  P00000142      F 0-17         10              0             345    13650
1000001  P00004842      F 0-17         10              0            3412    13645
1000001  P00025442      F 0-17         10              0             129    15416
1000001  P00051442      F 0-17         10              0            8170     9938
1000001  P00051842      F 0-17         10              0             480     2849
1000001  P00057542      F 0-17         10              0             345       NA
1000001  P00058142      F 0-17         10              0            3412    11051
1000001  P00058242      F 0-17         10              0            3412       NA
1000001  P00059442      F 0-17         10              0            6816    16622
1000001  P00064042      F 0-17         10              0            3412     8190'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = T)
```

Then we group by "Master_Category", and fill in any `NA` values with the group mean using `ifelse` inside of `mutate`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df.new <- df %>% 
  group_by(Master_Category) %>% 
  mutate(Purchase = ifelse(is.na(Purchase), mean(Purchase, na.rm = T), Purchase))

   User_ID Product_ID Gender Age   Occupation Marital_Status Master_Category Purchase
     <int> <fct>      <lgl>  <fct>      <int>          <int>           <int>    <dbl>
 1 1000001 P00000142  FALSE  0-17          10              0             345    13650
 2 1000001 P00004842  FALSE  0-17          10              0            3412    13645
 3 1000001 P00025442  FALSE  0-17          10              0             129    15416
 4 1000001 P00051442  FALSE  0-17          10              0            8170     9938
 5 1000001 P00051842  FALSE  0-17          10              0             480     2849
 6 1000001 P00057542  FALSE  0-17          10              0             345    13650
 7 1000001 P00058142  FALSE  0-17          10              0            3412    11051
 8 1000001 P00058242  FALSE  0-17          10              0            3412    10962
 9 1000001 P00059442  FALSE  0-17          10              0            6816    16622
10 1000001 P00064042  FALSE  0-17          10              0            3412     8190
```

Comment: Thanks jdobres
I took some time to understand because of the %>% symbol but eventually figured out.